# How to know class type when reading data from file?

Tags: c#, file, class

I have 3 classes. 'Product' is the base class. 'Book' and 'Software' is the class that I inherit to 'Product' class. First I write it to file and I want to read it back to know whether it 'Book' or 'Software' class. Could anyone help me please?

Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProductMainten
{
    public class ProductDB
    {
        private const string dir = @"C:\C# 2012 Soben\Files\";
        private const string path = dir + "ProductsCh14.txt";

        public static List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

            StreamReader textIn = new StreamReader(
                new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

            while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
            {
                string row = textIn.ReadLine();   
                string[] columns = row.Split('|');

                Product product = new Product();
                product.Code = columns[0];
                product.Description = columns[1];
                product.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(columns[2]);
                products.Add(product);
            }
            textIn.Close();
            return products;
        }

        public static void SaveProducts(List<Product> products)
        {
            StreamWriter textOut = new StreamWriter(
                new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));

            foreach (Product product in products)
            {
                if(product.GetType().Name == "Book")
                {
                    WriteBook((Book)product, textOut);
                }
                else if(product.GetType().Name == "Software")
                {
                    WriteSoftware((Software)product, textOut);
                }
            }
            textOut.Close();
        }

        private static void WriteBook(Book product, StreamWriter textOut)
        {
            WriteBase(product, textOut);
            textOut.Write(product.Author + "\n");
        }
        private static void WriteSoftware(Software product, StreamWriter textOut)
        {
            WriteBase(product, textOut);
            textOut.Write(product.Version + "\n");
        }
        private static void WriteBase(Product product, StreamWriter textOut)
        {
            textOut.Write(product.Code + "|");
            textOut.Write(product.Description + "|");
            textOut.Write(product.Price + "|");
        }

    }

}
```

This is the code and for writing to file that's ok

Comment: Where do you create the Book or Software?

Comment: In different class.

Comment: You only serialize data, I suggest serialize property names too. you can use JSON or XML for serialization.

Comment: Is it impossible to use file IO?

Comment: A not good way use string contains! use  textOut.Write("Author : "+product.Author + "\n"); and in GetProducts : coloums.Contains("Author") mean that row is Book.

Comment: JSON or XML is string you can keep in file!

Comment: I can't tell from your code if it's even possible to determine what type of product a product is from the data that you write out. Unless product.Code somehow contains this information coded into it, then the only option you have is to try to regex match the last column (which would be either Author or Version) to some pattern... but the problem is, what if Version is also some kind of a word, not a typical numeric string with major.minor. etc?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to determine the type from what I see, what you do is you write something like this:

`MyCode|MyDescription|MyPrice|MyAdditionalProperty`

There is no way you can detect type from this string unless there are some additional rules imposed on the inherited classes properties.

What you can do is add this information as your first element:

```
textOut.Write(product.GetType() + "|"); // You can write a switch instead to write your own string instead of a full name
```

Then when you read your data you first read the type moniker, after you do that you write a switch to create an instance of your class or use reflection if you write the full type.

P.S. I would suggest to look in some standardized libraries (or built-in methods) to do the serialization/deserialization instead of writing it yourself unless you have a good reason not not.